# is it possible to have more than rest parameter as function arguments in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Can we have two or more rest parameters in function arguments using ES6? Anyone please explain about that?

```
function f(a, b, ...args1, c, ...arg2) {
    //do somthing
}
```

is this is possible with es6?

Comment: No, not really. Think about it, it's easy to take the first parameter and assign it to `a`, the second and assign it to `b` but how many do you assign to `args1`? Note that _any_ amount is valid.

Comment: okay. could you please help me out to specify length of arguments for args1 ?

Comment: no; it's "rest" as in "the rest"

Answer (score 2):

No.

From [rest parameters on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters):

> If **the last** named argument of a function is prefixed with `...`, it becomes an array whose elements from `0` (inclusive) to `theArgs.length` (exclusive) are supplied by the actual arguments passed to the function.

(emphasis mine)

If it's "the last", it can obviously be only one.

Comment: Are you saying that the last agrument can be rest (...). or can we have the middle one as rest(...)?

Comment: @user2063756 Only the last can be rest.

Comment: REST syntax collects multiple elements and "condenses" them into a single element.

Answer (score 2):

No, because the result wouldn't be well defined.

For example, if you called

```
f(1,2,3,4,5);
```

then there would be different reasonable possibilities:

```js
a = 1;
b = 2;
args1 = [];
c = 3;
args2 = [4,5];
```

```js
a = 1;
b = 2;
args1 = [3];
c = 4;
args2 = [5];
```

```js
a = 1;
b = 2;
args1 = [3,4];
c = 5;
args2 = [];
```

```js
a = 1;
b = 2;
args1 = [3,4,5];
c = undefined;
args2 = [];
```